# Exit android application

Tags: android, android-activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

and use this method

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

I'm developing an application and at the last activity I need to exit it, I have used the above methods which exits the application the problem is it exists the ONLY the activity and the application runs in background (seen in the task manager). Whenever I load the application again it starts with where I exit it (the last activity).

is there any code to exit it completely and also remove form background(task manager).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change the behaviour of your Activities in the Manifest. Read up on SingleInstance,SingleTop etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To exit your application, return to your root activity (the activity that is the first one the launcher starts) this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyRootActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addExtra("exit", "true");
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the task stack down to the root activity and then start the root activity again with this intent.

In your root activity, in `onCreate()` you need to determine wether to exit based on the extras in the intent, like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("exit")) {
    // User wants to exit
    finish();
}
```

You also say something about removing your app from the task manager. If you are referring to the "list of recent apps" this isn't a list of the "running applications", it is a list of the applications that the user recently used. Just because your app shows up there does not mean that it is running.

If you really want your app not to show up in the "list of recent apps", just add this to the manifest entry for your root activity:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you simply not use

```
this.finish()
```

?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to call `finish();` then you can also add

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Note that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is only available starting from API 11 (Android 3.0).

Answer (score 1):

Start your last activity with this code to clear all the activity stack. When you will press the back button or call `finish()` it will exit the activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityD.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Be aware that FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is only available from API 11
For more info, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

When you call `startActivity(intent);` add `finish();` after it to close the old activity (unless you want to come back to that activity in the future)

so you code will look like:

```
startActivity(intent);  
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent finishapp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
finishapp.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
finishapp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(finishapp);
```

Comment: I am not able to understand what have you changed except renaming variable intent to finishapp.

Comment: I was not attentive. I copy code from my project, it works for me. I close app from second activities with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:noHistory` flag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to finish the activity by calling

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
   activity.this.finish();
```

or You can call the destroy method in your activity

```
   @Override     
   public void onDestroy()
    {
      super.onDestroy();
      finish();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my working code

on your exit button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
mainIntent.putExtra("close", true);
startActivity(mainIntent);
finish();
```

that code is to close any other activity and bring MainActivity on top
now on your MainActivity:

```
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("close", false)){
    finish();
}
```