# how to close android app completely

Tags: android, back-button, back-button-control, close-application

I created an android application with a logout option in `onCreateOptionsMenu`. The Logout works perfectly but when I press the back button again it takes me to the previous activity, and when it gets a null value it redirects to login screen. Now my login screen appears again and again. I want to close the app completely when I press the back button but don't know how.

Here is my code to handle the back button press in the login screen:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("BidNEMO")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
         Main.super.onBackPressed();
         finish();
         }
         }).create().show();
     }
```

please help guyss..

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14316135/1777090)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Proper Way to use onBackPressed()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413700/android-proper-way-to-use-onbackpressed)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To `Quit Application` on Button click use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Try it..

To kill the complete app and remove it from `Running`app list kill the app through its `pid`(its nasty)... use this lines before above code.

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Comment: you are just calling home via intent. How is it different from calling another activity's intent. i dont think the app will close. instead it will minimize.

Comment: whats your requirement ??

Comment: I just want to make sure that  the above code *Actually Quits* the app or just brings home screen on front. just to be clear :)

Comment: It Quits the app... Do check it

Comment: **Only** if you also include `super.onBackPressed()` and no other activity is in the `backstack` other wise it does't.

Comment: It was a general answer.... i have just posted the required code which can be used anywhere.. and i have clearly mentioned `on Button` click.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47956/discussion-between-smr-and-ryderz)

Comment: KillProcess should be killProcess, the first letter K be small k, fixed.

Comment: Thank you guys! Saved my neck, also the chat was helpful!

Answer (score 24):

If you want to close application completely you should use `finishAffinity();` instead of `finish()`  .
It will clear all stack of activities previously opened by an application.

Comment: `finishAffinity()` is only available in API level 16 or higher.

Answer (score 12):

**For API 21 and up**

[`finishAndRemoveTask()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAndRemoveTask())

You can call this to close the app completely. All activities will `finish()` and the app is removed from the task list.

Comment: it didn't work when I have another activity below current activity. finishAffinity worked however.

Comment: You can check before if the activity is the root activity with `isTaskRoot()`. Then it works great.

Answer (score 5):

To Finish an Activity I'm using this code:

```
public void appExit () {
    this.finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}  //close method
```

or kill Process with this code:

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Comment: KillProcess should be killProcess, the first letter K be small k, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

For Xamarin Users:

```
int pid = Android.OS.Process.MyPid();
Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(pid);
```

put it in your `OnDestroy()` function.

**Edit**:

After investigating it thoroughly, I found out that even the above code I wrote does not "Kill" the app totally (deleting it from task manager - "recent apps"). Eventually, after a lot of code tryouts, I managed to figure something out, Overriding "Finish" functions with this code:

```
public override void Finish()
    {
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            base.FinishAndRemoveTask();
        }
        else
        {
            base.Finish();
        }
    }
```

this is the sole solution for that question!

Answer (score 0):

Even if it looks ok killing process will cause you headache in future. 
You can ensure this by following use case:

1. call several activities to populate activities stack
2. call android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
3. open your application

**OBSERVED**: Your application opens not from main activity in inconsistent way. This is because Android consider killing of process like crash.

You can find more detailed information here: 
[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 0):

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myUid());
```

I think this is better.
How about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Closing the application with process removal, it gives the result of a smooth closing and removal of all application processes after 100 milliseconds:

[image]

---

```
override fun exit() {
    coroutine.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        finishAndRemoveTask()
        delay(100)
        exitProcess(0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used this method. It already worked for me. I use this technique with Jetpack Compose peoject.

```
val context = LocalContext.current

BackHandler {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```