# Exit Android app without caching in the background

Tags: android, memory-management

When exiting my app, the app is still cached in the background. How can I prevent this or release it from cache when exiting ?

[image]

Please do only answer, if you have a solution or hint . I have my reasons for doing this, so please don't ask counterquestions like "why do you want doing this ?" or "let the os doing the memory management" :-)

I am exiting the app by calling

```
finish();
```

Comment: how are you exiting the app...though code?can you post your code?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130493/how-to-close-android-app-completely/21130567#21130567

Comment: if your app has any service it run at background

Comment: @Mayank Saini : Thanks for helping . I am calling finish().

Comment: @appu bala: Thanks for helping . My app has no service. Its only an activity

Comment: ok i got solution, but please, do not ask counterquestions(it have to be done this way, becuase thats how Android OS works) - reboot the system :)

Comment: @Mayank Saini. This helped me. Killing the process is a bit primitve and brutal, but it helps.

Comment: @Selvin : No solution. I did not want to bother anyone with me counterquestion statement.

Comment: @Mayank Saini. This was the wrong answer ( it was not me that give -2 points :-) ). Do the answer with the killing process that was also mentoined in the link. Then I can accept it.

Comment: done man...edited...and now you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Quit Application on Button click use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.KillProcess(pid);
```

Comment: you are just calling home via intent. How is it different from calling another activity's intent. i dont think the app will close. instead it will minimize.

Comment: @Mayank Saini. This was the wrong answer ( it was not me that give -2 points :-) ). Do the answer with the killing process that was also mentoined in the link. Then I can accept it.

Comment: I guess you could remove the Intent Part of your answer ?