# Closing Android application programmatically

Tags: android, exit

I am working on an `Android` project the requirement is as follows: if any `exceptions` occur we need to exit the application by showing `error` message.

I am aware that `Android` doesn't allow to exit application programmatically so other work around should be to freeze the application that is user should not be able to do anything in the application. But how do I implement this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130493/how-to-close-android-app-completely/21130567#21130567

Answer (score 5):

hey call this function when error occurs
its simple

```
public void close()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void quit() {
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

(But using `system.exit()` is a bad approach in android. Better to use `finish()` )

OR

```
Intent i= new Intent(getapplicationcontext,TARGETACTIVITY.class);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: -1 for system.exit() without explaining why it's bad.

Comment: i think a android developer must know this and if YOU not knowing then google it.. here we are not for TEACHING.. here just for solving problems and finding solution..@simon

Comment: You misunderstand me.  system.exit() should only be used in special cases.  My downvote is because you proposed it as an answer and beginners would not know that it's bad unless you told them.  You have now edited the question, so I cancelled my vote.  And, I disagree with you about teaching.  If you don't teach here, then bad developers are born and the whole Android world suffers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. this is this....

Comment: if i use first solution, broadcast receicers( push ) are working properly which i registered in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
try{
-------
-----
----
}
Catch (Exception e)
{
exception.printStackTrace();//using alert box to show your exception. 
finish(); //use this one of your Application it will close the application. 
}
```

or else try to use service of create a new intent of your alertbox activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
             intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Write this code in your on backpressed override method

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just call

```
 System.exit();
```

in your catch block

Comment: But using system.exit() is a bad approach in android. Instead can use finish