# How to correctly exit a Processing sketch in Android

Tags: android, processing

I am currently building an app in Android Studio involving a Processing sketch.

Main class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import processing.android.PFragment;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class ClassMain extends Activity {
    /**************************************************/
    PApplet sketch;
    /**************************************************/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.class_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        sketch = new ClassSketch();
        PFragment fragment = new PFragment();
        fragment.setSketch(sketch);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
    /**************************************************/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {

        //ClassMain.this.finish();
    }
    /**************************************************/
    //It doesn't work if called from sketch...
    public void exits()
    {
        ClassMain.this.finish();
    }
    /**************************************************/
}
```

Processing Sketch:

```
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class ClassSketch extends PApplet {
    /*****************************************************************************/
    public void settings()
    {
        size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
    }
    /*****************************************************************************/
    public void setup()
    {
    }
    /*****************************************************************************/
    public void draw()
    {
        keykey();
    }
    public void keykey()
    {
        if(keyPressed)
        {
            if (key == CODED) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    //non of the following work:
                    //exit();
                    ClassMain j = new ClassMain();
                    j.exits();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problem, I want the the user, depending on some circumstances that I will add later in the sketch, to exit not only the sketch but the class that is hosting it  (`ClassMain`). 
When ever (in the sketch) something happens in my sketch, I want to be able to exit the whole `MainClass`, but I just happen to fail.
Thanks for the support.

Comment: Please link between crossposts: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/18230/how-to-correctly-exit-a-processing-sketch-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make sense:

```
ClassMain j = new ClassMain();
j.exits();
```

Here you're creating a new instance of `ClassMain`, and then immediately exiting. That won't do anything.

Instead, you need to tell the already-existing parent `ClassMain` to exit.

To do this, you need a reference to the parent `ClassMain` instance, which you can take into your `ClassSketch` constructor:

```
public class ClassSketch extends PApplet {

    private ClassMain parent;

    public ClassSketch(ClassMain parent){
       this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void keykey(){
       parent.exits();
    }
}
```

Then to pass the instance into the constructor, you can simply use the `this` keyword:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sketch = new ClassSketch(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary note to the above, don't forget to call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in your `onCreate()` function.

You can exit directly from your sketch by accessing `finish()` via: `this.getActivity().finish();`. Notice that in API level 16 and above, you also have available `this.getActivity().finishAffinity();` as commented in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130493/how-to-close-android-app-completely).

Lastly, if you press the *home* button, it calls `onStop()`, so the app lingers in Memory. If you press the *back* button, then `onDestroy()` gets called as well. If you call `finish()` as described, it is guaranteed `onDestroy()` gets called.

My two cents...

Kf